# How to do this in one function

Tags: prolog

I was wondering how to do the answer (or first function) to this question in Prolog only using one predicate?  The link I'm referring to is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883261/prolog-program-for-determining-whether-any-two-pairs-in-a-list-have-the-same-sum/1889563#1889563).

Here's an example of what I mean by only calling one predicate:

```
reverse([X|Y],Z,W) :- reverse(Y,[X|Z],W).
reverse([],X,X).
```

Comment: What do you mean? I can see only one “function” in the answer you linked. Although there are two versions of it. BTW, when you say “function” I'm assuming you mean “predicate”.

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry I do mean predicate and that I want to be able to figure out how to have it only call the one predicate.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean. Could you elaborate? Maybe provide an example?

Comment: I definitely can give an example.  Here's what I mean:
reverse([X|Y],Z,W) :- reverse(Y,[X|Z],W).
reverse([],X,X).

Comment: It's basically something that is only going to call one predicate (in the example above - only calls reverse).

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do and why do you want just one clause for the predicate?
personally I believe that having the ability to write many clauses is one of the great things of prolog and the code is more elegant and readable that way

Anyway, you will probably want to use or. assuming that you have the following clauses:

```
foo(Arg11,Arg12,Arg13):-
     (Body1).

foo(Arg21,Arg22,Arg23):-
     (Body2).

foo(Arg31,Arg32,Arg33):-
     (Body3).
```

you should first make sure that every clause has the same arguments (bye bye pattern matching there!):

```
foo(Arg1,Arg2,Arg3):-
         (Body1b).
foo(Arg1,Arg2,Arg3):-
         (Body2b).
foo(Arg1,Arg2,Arg3):-
         (Body3b).
```

and then you will use or (;):

```
foo(Arg1,Arg2,Arg3):-
    (Body1b)
    ; (Body2b)
    ; (Body3b).
```

for example,

```
reverse([X|Y],Z,W):-
    reverse(Y,[X|Z],W).
reverse([],X,X).
```

will become:

```
reverse(X,Y,Z):-
    X = [H|T], 
    reverse(T,[H|Y],X).
reverse(X,Y,Z):-
    X = [],
    Z = Y.
```

and then:

```
reverse(X,Y,Z):-
    (X = [H|T], 
    reverse(T,[H|Y],X) )
    ; (X = [],
        Z = Y).  *%ew ew ugly!*
```

regarding the example on your first post, there are two different predicates, each having just one clause. the second predicate has 2 arguments while the first one has 1 therefore they are different. The only way to "merge" them would be by simply calling the second one as has_equal_sums(List, _) in the place of the first.

To be honest, I dont see the point of doing this; I doubt you will not get any significant speedup and the code becomes way messier.
Of course, it's your code and there can be restrictions we dont know (that's why I asked what you want to accomplish)

Comment: I completely understand where you're coming from and it is messier probably.  I just wanted to be able to find a way where it would function the same but only call use the one predicate as the main call.

Comment: If I understand the question, it is not about having only one clause for a predicate, but about using only one predicate (possibly with many clauses).  Naturally such an artificial constraint on the implementation would risk being hard for a human to read.

Comment: huum, one predicate, many clauses... we could use a "master" predicate, myprogram/2. the first argument would be the predicate name and the second a list of arguments. something like myprogram(father,[john,kevin]). myprogram(mother,(liz,kevin)]. myprogram(grandfather,[X,Y]):-father(X,Z),father(Z,Y). and then we could use or and put them all in one clause. LOL

Comment: Yes, if we generalize from the example given **reverse/3**, we are allowed to an additional argument (perhaps more) to achieve the desired relation, just as in the example `reverse(X,[ ],Z)` would produce the reverse of list X as output Z.  The "function" linked to asks for choosing four members of a list such that the sum of two of them equals the sum of the other two, so the use of at least the + operator and built-in predicate **is/2** would have to be allowed as well as the recursively defined "one predicate".